# Cmake cannot find boost library directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, cmake, mlpack

I am trying to install mlpack on Visual Studio 2010 using Intel Compiler and I'm following this link - https://keon.io/mlpack/mlpack-on-windows/

I am trying to run certain CMake command and it is failing with the error -

```
C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\build> cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64" -T"Intel C++ compiler XE 14.0" 
-DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/mlpack-.1.1/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/naive/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" 
-DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/mlpack-.1.1/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/ative/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" 
-DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/projects/armadillo-.800.1/include" 
-DARMADILLO_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/projects/armadillo-.800.1/build/Debug/armadillo.lib" 
-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost.1.63.0.0\lib\native\include" 
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost_libs" -DDEBUG=OFF -PROFILE=OFF ..


Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.63.0
Boost include path:
C:/projects/mlpack-2.1.1/packages/boost.1.63.0.0/lib/native/include

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

      boost_program_options
      boost_unit_test_framework
      boost_serialization

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:279 (find_package)
```

However, the directory `C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost_libs` has all the required libraries

CMakeLists.txt has this on line 279

```
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
"1.49.0" "1.50.0" "1.51.0" "1.52.0" "1.53.0" "1.54.0" "1.55.0" "1.63.0")
find_package(Boost 1.49 #Line 279
  COMPONENTS
    program_options
    unit_test_framework
    serialization
  REQUIRED
)
```

I changed line 279 to `find_package(Boost 1.49` but no use. 
I also tried changing '\' to '/' and vice-versa. What could be the error?

Comment: `What could be the error?` - You have Boost libraries incompatible with generator `Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64`.

Comment: I am using Intel compiler right!

Comment: Pass option `-DBoost_DEBUG=on` to `cmake`, and see which library files are actually searched. Then compare these files with ones you have.

Comment: I am getting the error if I'm using Intel toolkit. If I'm not using intel toolkit and just msvc, I'm getting some other error but boost libraries are found. Why is intel not finding boost libraries?

Comment: `Why is intel not finding boost libraries?` - Because Boost libraries are intended to use with **specific compiler**. Msvc uses ones libraries, Intel compiler uses **another** ones.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your CMake version has no support for Boost 1.63.

Support for Boost 1.63 was introduced in CMake 3.7.2; update CMake and you will be fine.